# How to encrypt with python ctr mode

Tags: python, node.js, encryption, aes

I have applied the the encryption algorithm in nodejs and now I need to decrypt the same using python how would I be able to do this.

The JS code is -

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const data = "Hello there, help me to decrypt using python"
let iv = 'N13FF0F4ACC4097M'
let key = '312s389g2r5b54rd'
const cp = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-128-ctr', key, iv)
let enc = cp.update(data, 'utf-8', 'base64') + cp.final('base64')
console.log(enc)


#output = 401Auq5PXMVzcbTJXl5hgLRccO8RSKFnB4VjsQuzkUNwJKMmwWHNqILIa1Q=
```

Here is code i used in pyhton

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Util import Counter
data = "Hello there, help me to decrypt using python"
iv = b'N13FF0F4ACC4097M'
key = b'312s389g2r5b54rd'
ctr_e = Counter.new(64, prefix=iv)
cp = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CTR, counter=ctr_e)
enc = cp.encrypt(data)
print(enc)
```

I am getting error in applying the correct way. Can anyone help to resolve this issue.

Comment: Can. you show the errors you're getting?

Comment: ValueError: Size of the counter block (24 bytes) must match block size (16)

Comment: This is the error.   `TypeError: CTR counter function returned string not of length 16`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is displayed because your `Counter` implementation violates (see [`Counter`](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/util/util.html#Crypto.Util.Counter.new)):

> It must hold that len(prefix) + nbits//8 + len(suffix) matches the block size of the underlying block cipher.

In the NodeJS code neither a prefix nor a suffix is used, but the whole IV as counter value, i.e. `nBits` equals `128` and `initial_value` equals the value of the IV:

```py
ctr_e = Counter.new(128, initial_value=int.from_bytes(b'N13FF0F4ACC4097M', 'big'))
cp = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CTR, counter=ctr_e)
```

Alternatively and shorter (see [here](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/classic.html#ctr-mode)):

```py
cp = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CTR, nonce=b'', initial_value=b'N13FF0F4ACC4097M')
```

With this fix (one or the other), the Python code provides the ciphertext of the NodeJS code.